# Phonegap xcode jquery mobile css dont load it

Tags: css, xcode, load, simulator

i installed phonegap on xcode and i create a new project. I included jquery mobile in my project but when i start it on the simulator it's not load the css files. When i open the same code in a Browser then it loads the css files of jquery mobile.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to counter this is to include the styles as a `<style>` tag in the header of *all* of your HTML pages for the app.

There must be a better way, but I've never gotten linked CSS files to work properly.

Comment: i copied the all content of the css file from jquery mobile and paste it in the html file. The result is the same!